# sql php single quote or apostrophe

Tags: php, sql, apostrophe

How do i search @ display variable that contains single quote ( ' ) by using sql & php?

Ex:
CompanyName = ABC'S ENTERPRISE

```
$comp_name (as variable)

$tsql = "SELECT CompanyName from tbl.company WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$comp_name%'";
```

Comment: Look into prepared statements and bind variables, this will solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Use statements, but putting double quotes around the query should allow you to use unescaped single quotes in the actual query string.

Comment: any example of that?

Answer (score 0):

use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) php function like this

```
$tsql = "SELECT CompanyName from tbl.company WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%".addslashes($comp_name)."%'";
```

for you example

> CompanyName = ABC'S ENTERPRISE

addslashes will add a slash like

> ABC\'S ENTERPRISE

Now the resulting query will be

```
SELECT CompanyName from tbl.company WHERE CompanyName LIKE 'ABC\'S ENTERPRISE'
```

Comment: add slash in database(company name) also? so that in database for that company will be ABC\'S ENTERPRISE?

Comment: how select query adds data into the database?

Comment: can you explain your problem in brief

Comment: based on query that i already given.. i want to search company with ( ' ),by using this url -> http://localhost/api/company.php?comp_name=ABC'S ENTERPRISE

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

$comp_name (as variable)

$tsql = 'SELECT CompanyName from tbl.company WHERE CompanyName LIKE "%'.$comp_name.'%"';

Comment: error : Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero